# How to add date in database - paypal

Tags: php, paypal, integration

I have problem with integration paypal on the website. I would like add data to database after successful transaction. Payment paypal is working but not add data to database. I don't know how it do.

index.php

```
    <form action="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" target="_top" id="division_form">



<div class="current_tier" id="ct" style="float: left; width: 45%; margin-right: 5%;">
                        <select id="current_tier_id" name="current_tier_id" onchange="calcBoost(division_price_matrix, discount);">
                            <option>Bronze</option>
                            <option selected = "selected">Silver</option>
                            <option>Gold</option>
                            <option>Platinum</option>
                            <option>Diamond</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                    <div class="current_division" id="cd" style="float: left; width: 45%;" >
                        <select name="current_division_number" onchange="calcBoost(division_price_matrix, discount);">
                            <option value="5">5</option>
                            <option value="4">4</option>
                            <option value="3">3</option>
                            <option value="2">2</option>
                            <option selected = "selected" value="1">1</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>

                    <div class="current_lp" id="lp" style="float: left; width: 65%">
                        <select onchange="calcBoost(division_price_matrix, discount);">
                            <option>0-20 LP</option>
                            <option>20-40 LP</option>
                            <option>40-60 LP</option>
                            <option>60-80 LP</option>
                            <option>80-99 LP</option>
                            <option>100 LP</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="before_tier">
                <div class="current_tier_img" id="cti" style = "background-image: url(http://eloedge.com/_FILES/eloscript/images/silver_1.png)"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="right" style = "height: 200px; float: left;">
                <div class="form_right" style = "float: left; width: 220px;">
                    <div class="desired_tier"  id="dt" style="float: left; width: 45%; margin-right: 5%">
                        <select name="desired_tier_id" onchange="calcBoost(division_price_matrix, discount);">
                            <option>Bronze</option>
                            <option>Silver</option>
                            <option selected = "selected">Gold</option>
                            <option>Platinum</option>
                            <option>Diamond</option>
                            <option>Master</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                    <div class="desired_division" id="dd" style="float: left; width: 45%;">
                        <select name="desired_division_number" onchange="calcBoost(division_price_matrix, discount);">
                            <option selected = "selected" value="5">5</option>
                            <option value="4">4</option>
                            <option value="3">3</option>
                            <option value="2">2</option>
                            <option value="1">1</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                    <div style="float: left; width: 25%; margin-right: 5%"><label style="padding-top: 10px" for="division_region">Region:</label></div>
                    <div style="float: left; width: 65%">
                            <select name="division_region" onchange="division_info_update()">
                                <option value="na">North America</option>
                                <option value="euw">Europe West</option>
                                <option value="eun">Europe North & East</option>
                            </select>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="before_tier">
                <div class="desired_tier_img" id="dti" style = "background-image: url(http://eloedge.com/_FILES/eloscript/images/gold_5.png)"></div>
                </div>
            </div></div>
        <div id="payment_details" class="div_center" style="float: none;width: 675px;margin: auto">
            <div class="payment_details">
                <div class="child">
                <label for="division_user">Username:</label>
                <span id="division_user_span" title="">
                    <input type="text" id="division_user" name="division_user" required="" onkeyup="division_info_update()" />
                </span>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="payment_details">
            <div class="child">
                <label for="division_password">Password:</label>
                <span id="division_password_span" title="">
                    <input type="text" id="division_password" name="division_password" required="" onkeyup="division_info_update()" />
                </span>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="payment_details">
            <div class="child">
                <label for="division_summoner">Summoner Name:</label>
                <input type="text" id="division_summoner" name="division_summoner" required="" onkeyup="division_info_update()" />
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>

 <div id="price" style="float: left; width: 100%; text-align: center;">Price: $1 EUR</div>



                <input type="hidden" name="lc" value="EUR" />
                <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick" />
                <input type="hidden" name="business" value="maksymilianzuzel2@gmail.com" />
                <input type="hidden" name="hosted_button_id" value="3AV9FWRLTZ3KL">
                <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="EUR" />
                <input type="hidden" name="item_number" value="0-20 LP Silver 1 to Gold 5" />
                <input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="Rating Boost" />
                <input id="boost_amount" type="hidden" name="amount" value = "0"/>
                <input type="hidden" name="notify_url" value="https://ratingboost.net/userpanel/payed.php" />
                <input type="hidden" name="custom" value="" />

                <input style = "" type="image" alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online!" name="submit" src="http://eloedge.com/_FILES/eloscript/images/paypal.png" />

                <img src="http://www.sandbox.paypal.com/en_US/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1" border="0" />

            </form>
```

payed.php

```
<?php

    session_start();

    if (!isset($_SESSION['zalogowany']))
    {
        header('Location: ../login.php');
        exit();
    }



    $current_tier_id = $_POST['current_tier_id'];
    $desired_tier_id = $_POST['desired_tier_id'];
    $current_division_number = $_POST['current_division_number'];
    $desired_division_number = $_POST['desired_division_number'];
    $division_user = $_POST['division_user'];
    $division_summoner = $_POST['division_summoner'];
    $price = $_POST['amount'];


$today = date("m.d.Y G:i:s"); 
$id = $_SESSION['id'];
echo 'CURRENT: <br />';
echo 'Division: '.$current_tier_id.'<br />';
echo 'Number: '.$current_division_number.'<br /><br /><br />';

echo 'Desired: <br />';
echo 'Division: '.$desired_tier_id.'<br />';
echo 'Number: '.$desired_division_number.'<br /><br /><br />';

echo 'User: '.$division_user.'<br />';
echo 'Summoner name: '.$division_summoner.'<br />';
echo 'Price: '.$price.'<br />';




require_once "../connect.php";
$polaczenie = new mysqli($host, $db_user, $db_password, $db_name);
if ($polaczenie->query("INSERT INTO leagueoflegendsbought VALUES (NULL, '$current_tier_id', '$current_division_number', '$desired_tier_id','$desired_division_number','$division_user','$division_summoner','$price','$id')"))
{               
    echo 'Udało się!';
    header('Location: index.php');
}
else
{
    throw new Exception($polaczenie->error);
}

?>
```

Comment: Can we see some code?

Comment: I edited the post

Comment: Simple: it's your `<input style = "" type="image"...` that isn't firing.

Comment: `echo 'Udało się!';
    header('Location: index.php');
}` and you are outputting before header; so that's 2 things that are against you. Error reporting would have told you about it but you're not checking for errors anywhere.

Comment: Plus, since you didn't specify the columns it's going into, the number of columns **must match** the number in the values; check for errors on the query, you're also **not** doing that. The form's action is also failing you. So, your code is failing on many levels.

Comment: So what should i do?